# how to properly make call functions of trigonometry in degrees

Tags: c++

In this program I am forced to make a call function for 3 trig functions "sind, cosd, tand", and I have to invoke them to the main program. I am clueless on how to make them work. I also have to have the input values in degrees. I also don't know what the 'while' statement is supposed to equal. Any tips would greatly be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

double sind();

int main(void)
{
double s, c, t;

char select;

    std::cout << "Trigonometric functions in degrees." << std::endl     << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Please select a funcion to be performed : " <<     std::endl << std::endl;


do
{
    std::cout << "S/s: sin, " << "C/c: cos, " << "T/t: tan, " <<     "E/e: Exit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "please enter your selection. \n";
    std::cin >> select;

    switch (select)
    {
        case 'S' : case 's':
            std::cout << "Please enter a value in degrees : ";
            std::cin >> s;
            std::cout << "sin(" << s << " degrees" << ")" << "=" <<     sind << std::endl;
            break;
        case 'C' : case 'c':
            std::cout << "Please enter a value in degrees : ";
            std::cin >> c;
            std::cout << "cos(cos) : " << "cosd "<< std::endl;
            break;
        case 'T' : case 't':
            std::cout << "Please enter a value in degrees : ";
            std::cin >> t;
            std::cout << "tan(tan) : " << "tand" << std::endl;
            break;
        case 'E' : case 'e' :
            std::cout << "Program has terminated. Goodbye." <<     std::endl;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "You have entered an invalid code. Please     try again." << std::endl;
        }
} while (select != 'e');
}
```

Comment: Convert degrees to radians, call the standard library functions.

Comment: You can use a conversion:  `const double one_radian = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795 / 180.0;`.  Multiply your degrees by `one_radian`.

Comment: In `<< sind << std::endl;` did you mean to print `sind()` instead of `sind` ? `sind` is a function.

Comment: Reduce your quantity of compares by using `std::toupper` or `std::tolower` before the `switch` statement.

Comment: @François Andrieux I'm trying to use sind, but I don't know how to use it correctly

Comment: @TylerRodriguez perhaps a strong first step in learning c++ would be to understand what [functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions) are and how to use them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @François Andrieux said, you should really learn how functions work in C++.
Here´s some help with your specific problem:
To calculate the sine of a angle in degrees you have to first convert it to radians:

```
double s_rad = s / 180 * PI;
```

You have to define Pi between your include statements and the start of your main function

```
#define PI 3.14159265
```

You can then pass this value to the function by writing it in bracket behind the function name:

```
double result = sin ( s_rad );
```

Or directly

```
double result = sin (s / 180 * PI);
```